# ASP Net Core StructureMap HybridLifecycle replacement

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, structuremap

I'm currently in the process of updating a library that was built for ASP.NET MVC 5 to use with the latest asp net core 1.0 that was using StructureMap to do DI. However, I've noticed that the Hybrid lifecycle in StructureMap is legacy now and is no longer supported. Is there a replacement for this lifecycle out there, or a way to get the same functionality?

```
For<SessionContext>()
    .LifecycleIs<HybridLifecycle>()
    .Use<SessionContext>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own asp net lifecycle class to match the same functionality of the old Hybrid lifecycle with the new ASP .Net core.

```
public class AspNetCoreLifecycle : ILifecycle {

    private readonly object mapLock = new object();

    public string Description => "Asp Net Core Lifecycle object";

    private readonly Container container;
    private Dictionary<HttpContext, IObjectCache> contextMap = new Dictionary<HttpContext, IObjectCache>();

    public AspNetCoreLifecycle(Container cont) {
        this.container = cont;

    }

    public void EjectAll(ILifecycleContext context) {

        lock (mapLock) {
            foreach (var kvp in contextMap) {
                kvp.Value.DisposeAndClear();
            }

            contextMap = new Dictionary<HttpContext, IObjectCache>();
        }
    }

    public IObjectCache FindCache(ILifecycleContext context) {

        var accessor = container.GetInstance<IHttpContextAccessor>();

        lock (mapLock) {
            if (!contextMap.ContainsKey(accessor.HttpContext)) {
                contextMap.Add(accessor.HttpContext, new LifecycleObjectCache());
            }

            return contextMap[accessor.HttpContext];
        }
    }
}
```